# Converting possible lvalue reference template to lvalue

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    TWithoutReferenceType t1 = Magic(t); //some magic here
}
```

`TWithoutReference` is the same type of `T` but without reference, so for example:

```
Magic(int i) -> int i
Magic(int& i) -> int i
Magic(int&& i) -> int i
```

I don't know if this is possible for rvalue references or what it could mean in practice though.

**WHY I NEED IT:**

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
function<ReturnType(Args...)> memoize(const function<ReturnType(Args...)>& func)
{
    return ([=](Args... args) mutable {
        static map<tuple<Args...>, ReturnType> cache;
        tuple<Args...> t(args...);
        auto result = cache.insert(make_pair(t, ReturnType{}));
        ...
```

So for example if `Args ...` is `vector<double> &` and I change the order of the elements, the correspondent key in `cache` is changed also, and I don't want that this happens, so I don't want that a key change in the future as side effect.

Sorry if I posted the whole code, but I'm afraid that if I make it simpler I'll lose the point of the question.

Comment: Are you saying that you want `tuple<Args...>` to be a tuple of non-reference types

Comment: Exactly. And I think that this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742877/remove-reference-from-stdtuple-members) question

Comment: OK, let us know if that solution worked for you and I'll close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're finding is [std::remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference):

> If the type T is a reference type, provides the member typedef type which is the type referred to by T. Otherwise type is T.
>
> Possible implementation
>
> ```
> template< class T > struct remove_reference      {typedef T type;};
> template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&>  {typedef T type;};
> template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&&> {typedef T type;};
> ```

You might implement `Magic` as

```
template <typename T> 
typename remove_reference<T>::type Magic(T t) { 
    return t; 
}
```

Comment: So can you write the function that I'm look for using `std::remove_reference` please?

Answer (score 2):

You have several choices including:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type Magic(const T& t) { return t; }
```

or

```
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type Magic(T&& t) { return t; }
```

Comment: you probably want `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type` as the return type in the second one.

Comment: @M.M Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: @songyuanyao: Not if you provide the template parameter, i.e: `Magic<const int&>(my_int);`, but that change nothing for `Magic(my_int);`

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry didn't get it. I meant `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type` and `std::remove_reference_t<T>` is the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: There are the same but `remove_reference_t` is only available since c++14 (and OP's tag is c++11).

Comment: @Jarod42 Fine, got it.