# structured bindings, reference ? Is it possible to remove them

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Let's say I have such a tuple.

```
std::tuple<int &, int> tuple{};
```

I want to do something like that :

```
auto [i1, i2] = tuple; // Here i1 is lvalue reference, i2 is int
```

i1 is a lvalue reference because the first value on the tuple is one lvalue reference.
However, I did not write `auto &[i1, i2]`. So, is there a possibility to "remove" the reference in this case? So that I got i1 and i2 as "simple" int.
Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This structured binding is equivalent to:

```
auto e = tuple;  
auto&& i1 = e.get<1>();
auto&& i2 = e.get<2>();
```

Since `tuple` has type `std::tuple<int&, int>`, that is also the type of `e`.

The structured binding syntax doesn't have a flavour to remove references from inside the `tuple`. However you can make a helper function to do that [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742877/remove-reference-from-stdtuple-members). Here is a working example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... T>
using tuple_with_removed_refs = std::tuple<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type...>;

template <typename... T>
tuple_with_removed_refs<T...> remove_ref_from_tuple_members(std::tuple<T...> const& t) {
    return tuple_with_removed_refs<T...> { t };
}

int main()
{
    int x{5}, y{6};

    std::tuple<int& , int> t(x, y);

    auto [i1, i2] = remove_ref_from_tuple_members(t);

    std::cout << i1 << ' ' << i2 << '\n';
    i1 = 7; i2 = 8;
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
5 6
5 6
```

Comment: Hello, it is not exactly what we need but it made me understand that what I need is impossible ^^.
Thanks !