# Structured bindings mixing rvalues and lvalues in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, rvalue, lvalue, stdtuple

The commented line in the following snippet does not work as expected:

```
double a, b;
auto [c, d] = std::make_tuple<double, double&>([&]() -> double { return a; }(),
                                               [&]() -> double& { return b; }());
static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, decltype(c)>);
// static_assert(std::is_same_v<double&, decltype(d)>);    // Compile error!
```

Specifically, I would like to return both an rvalue and an lvalue in a single structured binding declaration. I have tried to declare `c` and `d` both using `auto&` and `auto&&`, but none of the approaches worked. **Is there a way to achieve the above desired behavior?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [structured bindings, reference ? Is it possible to remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215922/structured-bindings-reference-is-it-possible-to-remove-them)

Comment: what is `real_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::make_tuple<double, double&>(...)` returns `std::tuple<double, double>`, since it applies `std::decay` to the template arguments. In any case, you're not supposed to specify the template arguments for it, it can deduce them automatically.

To have a reference in the tuple, construct it using `std::tuple<double, double &>(...)`. Then your code works as you expect it to.