# How to get a removed-reference tuple type without using an instance in C++

Tags: c++, tuples, metaprogramming

I wrote a test framework for testing function output (see code below).

```cpp
    template <class FuncTy, class... IndexType>
    typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<typename function_helper<FuncTy>::arguments>::value == sizeof...(IndexType)
        and std::is_same_v<typename function_helper<FuncTy>::return_type, AnswerTy>
        and not is_member_function_pointer_v<FuncTy>, void>::type
        test(FuncTy func, IndexType... arg_indexes) {
        using function_args_tuple = typename function_helper<FuncTy>::arguments;
        using function_return_type = typename function_helper<FuncTy>::return_type;
  
        // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        function_args_tuple params;  /// error is here
        // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        /// .....
    }
```

It works well for functions that do not have references in arguments.

e.g.:

1. for fucntion `int f(int x, vector<int> y);` (i.e., no references in argument list), the type of `params` is a `std::tuple<int, vector<int>>`, so the `params` can instantiate normally with code above,
2. but for functions like `int f(int& x, vector<int>& y);` (i.e., one or more references in argument list), the type of `params` becomes `std::tuple<int&, vector<int>&>`, which is not able to instantiate with code above.

The type of the tuple `params` is affected by argument list of a function (done with another function), the type of the tuple is undefined, so I just cannot do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070218/how-to-get-from-a-tuple-to-a-tuple-of-references-to-elements-in-the-tuple) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742877/remove-reference-from-stdtuple-members), since both of the solutions in the two links use a `make_tuple` explictly and an instantiated tuple object.

So my question is how to remove the references without instantiate the tuple. (e.g., make `tuple<int&, vector<int>&>` to `tuple<int, vector<int>>`).

Or else if there is some ways to instantiate a tuple with references in the tuple's template argument list without hard-coded `make_tuple` calls.

Comment: You probably want to wrap each tuple element type with `std::decay_t<ArgumentType>`. That will transform references to values, C-style arrays to pointers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element type of the `tuple` through template partial specialization and apply [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) to those types to remove references, something like this

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<class Tuple>
struct decay_args_tuple;

template<class... Args>
struct decay_args_tuple<std::tuple<Args...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>;
};
```

Then you can get a `tuple` of the decay argument types through the helper class

```
decay_args_tuple<decltype(function_args_tuple)>::type params;
```

Note that the argument type is still required to be default constructible.